Absolutely vs Non-Absolutely Convergent Infinite Product
Consider the following standard infinite product:
$$
 \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}z \right)
$$
This product is not absolutely convergent because:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}z \right| \text{ has the same character as } \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}
$$
however, by writing it as:
$$
 \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{z}{4n+1} \right) \left( 1 + \frac{z}{4n-1} \right)
$$
it becomes absolutely convergent.
The key step in writing it out this way is the following:
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}z \right) = \lim_{N \to +\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{2N} \left( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}z \right)
$$
where I can consider $2N$ only, because the sequence associated to the product converges to 1.
I would like to know wether this analysis is correct or not, and if so, does that mean that "collecting product terms in different ways may change the character of convergence"? (I guess something similar happens for series if we collect terms of a conditionally convergent alternating sign series in a way such that we end up with a positive sign series which is absolutely convergent).
